# problems with a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Here is my view source:

```
<input id="ctl00_cp_ctrlNew_lendeeMe" type="radio" name="ctl00$cp$ctrlNew$whoBorrowed" value="lendeeMe" />
```

And I am trying to use this selector to check one of them, but it is not working:

```
$("input[@id$='lendeeMe']").attr('checked','checked');
```

but if I do this, it works fine:

```
$("#ctl00_cp_ctrlNew_lendeeMe").attr('checked','checked');
```

That is due tot he crazy way asp.net makes controls, so I figured using the previous selector would be easier.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using?

Because as [said here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the '@' symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.

So maybe you want to simply try:

```
$("input[id$='lendeeMe']").attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 3):

The `[@attr]` style selectors were removed in jQuery 1.3. (Deprecated in 1.2). Try removing the @ sign.

Or, base it off another attribute, like `$("input[value='lendeeMe']")`.

Answer (score 3):

$("input[id$='lendeeMe']").attr('checked','checked');
because "@" fell into disuse in jquery